# Neo4j database will not load in my desktop application on windows

Tags: neo4j

Please I am trying to access the Neo4j database via its browser. I have used both bolt//:localhost:7687 and http//:localhost:7474, and Username: "neo4j" and Password:"neo4j" but with no success. I can't even start a database instance.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled Neo4j on my computer; I have updated Powershell on my Windows 8.1 computer, yet I keep getting an error message whenever I try to run the Movie database in the desktop.

I have also looked into the log.log file, but can't seem to find anything other than that I should update Powershell, which I have done.

I have corresponded with a relations officer at Neo4j, over 30 emails, and still I can't access Neo4j database.

Could it have anything to do with my web browser? I use Mozilla Firefox.

Because I am unable to successfully connect to Neo4j database, I can't call the api in R Studio and run cypher queries.

Does Neo4j have a web version, which I could use, since the desktop version isn't working?

Please does anybody have any idea or advice on what I could do to resolve this problem? I am really exasperated right now.

Comment: Can you use the neo4j sandbox? You can create a new project but would be limited to 3 days. https://sandbox.neo4j.com/

Comment: Yes, thanks; that is what I have had to do. I can extend it for another 7 days too.